# HTTP Status Code: Not found error for AzureRM.Datafactoryv2 cmdlets in powershell

Tags: powershell

When i run `Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2ActivityRun` in PowerShell i get an error as shown below

> Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2ActivityRun : HTTP Status Code: NotFound
>   Error Code: NotFound
>   Error Message: Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'
>   Request Id: ID
>   Timestamp (Utc):05/31/2018 04:32:39
>   At line:2 char:1
>   + Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2ActivityRun -DataFactoryName "maxscadfdev" -R ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2ActivityRun], ErrorResponseException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.GetAzureDataFactoryActivityRunCommand

Comment: Share your code!

Answer (score 0):

Very likely you have pushed incorrect Resource Group Name.
Check the following steps:
1) update AzureRmDataFactoryV2 module first.
2) restart PowerShell session (if needed)
3) check the correctness of passing Resource Group Name

I have wrote post with more details:
https://sqlplayer.net/2018/09/notfound-status-code-when-working-with-adfv2-via-azurerm-datafactoryv2-powershell-module/